# Loading Data into iOS App from Server at Startup and Reusing It when Reloading Views

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am building an eCommerce app with SwiftUI that needs to retrieve some data from a server before loading many of the views. I am wondering the proper way to retrieve and store this data.

Currently, on the home page the app requests the server for the names of some images to be displayed, and then uses `AsyncImage` to load each image from the server. Currently I am creating a `@State` variable within the view to store the image names, and loading the data in a `.task`:

```
struct CoverImagesTabView: View {
    
    @State var coverImageNames: [String] = []

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ForEach(coverImageNames, id: \.self) { coverImage in
                CoverImageView(coverImage: coverImage)
                    .padding(.top, 10)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 15)
            } //: LOOP
        } //: TAB
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .always))
        .task {
            await getCoverImageNames { imageNames in
                coverImageNames = imageNames
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with the `getCoverImageNames` function looking like

```
import Alamofire

func getCoverImageNames(_ callback: @escaping (_ decoded: [String]) -> Void) async {
    AF.request("http://\(serverIP)/api/offerings/marketing/coverImages")
        .responseDecodable(of: [String].self) { response in
            if response.value != nil {
                callback(response.value ?? [])
                print("Cover image names retrieved")
            } else {
                print("Could not access cover image names")
            }
        }
}
```

The `coverImageNames` are then used within the `CoverImageView` to load the images. I plan to use the same strategy to retrieve other data, such as a list of products.

This method is a little clunky, mostly because it makes this call to the API to set the value of `coverImageNames` every time the view is reloaded; this data really only needs to be loaded once, at every app startup. Is there a specific way to do this in Swift?

If I create a class that conforms to `ObservableObject` and passing an instance of it as a `@StateObject` to this view, it solves the reloading issue, but isn't very efficient if I have to create a whole new class just to represent a `[String]` for the sole purpose of it only loading once.

I also considered using Core Data to save the data from the server, but that seems way overkill.

Is there a built-in way to load my data one time and then continue to reuse it every time a view is reloaded? Or is the state object method the most efficient/only way?

Comment: Your question is largely opinion based but the async/await keywords are misused in this code. I would suggest watching “Meet async/await” and Demystify SwiftUI.

Comment: @loremipsum Because I am not awaiting any asynchronous expressions within the function that I marked async, correct?
I believe I may have been at one point and forgot to remove it but thank you for the heads up.

Comment: Async await follows a very specific pattern and “callbacks” aren’t a part of it.

Comment: Have a look at this link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app 
[Managing model data in your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just create an Observable class and share an instance of it over the entire application through @EnvironmentObject.

If it doesn't change at all after loaded once, no need to use @StateObject because no need to update views.

```
class YourModel : ObservableObject {
    var coverImageNames: [String] = []

    init() {
        fetchImageNames()
    }

    func fetchImageNames() {
        // load the names of `some` images from the server using URLSession or whatnot and update coverImageNames
    }
}

struct YourApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(YourModel())
        }
    }
}

struct YourView1: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var m: YourModel
    var body: some View {
        // use m.coverImageNames
    }
}

struct YourView2: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var m: YourModel
    var body: some View {
        // use m.coverImageNames
    }
}
```

If you don't like to call AsyncImage in each view repeatedly, I would build a collection of UIImage during init so it could be reused in any views. Building the collection could be sync or async and both have pros/cons depending on situations so it's your choice.

Comment: any particular reason to define the `fetchImageNames()` as a method of the `YourModel` class? I implemented this `init()` function to load the image names (and then the images after the names, thanks for that tip) using a function defined in a separate file (full of networking functions), and then assigned the responses from the server in the completionHandler of said function

Comment: It's just personal preference for organizing code. Not a big deal :)